# export cpntools project to jpg/png

Tags: petri-net

i searched all around the web and could not find a way to export a CPN (Colored Petri Nets) model in [cpntools](http://cpntools.org/) to a jpg or png image.

[here](http://cpntools.org/documentation/tasks/verification/drawing_state_spaces_with) is a fuzzy article but not so informative and helpful.
is there any idea?

Comment: "Age of Empires I and II Campaign File ( Microsoft Corporation ) CPN stands for Age of Empires I and II Campaign File ( Microsoft Corporation )" <- is this the cpn you are talking about?

Comment: @kipe no! i meant colored petri nets, as i added tag *petri net*. i edited my question and inserted some another links. thank.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "Print net" tool to export your Petri net as an EPS file, then use an image conversion program to convert that to jpg or png.

More information can be found here:
http://cpntools.org/documentation/gui/palettes/net_tools/print_net

Note that I have had issues loading the exported EPS format in some editors (e.g. GIMP), but online conversion tools usually manage to convert them to other formats fine.